# Wicket - Init a Component with Loadable Detachable Model on click event

Tags: java, model, wicket, wicketstuff

I am adding ChildPanel in the constructor of Panel. When the Panel loads the child panel is rendered with the data that is returned by getData(). Below is the code.

**Panel**

```
public Panel(String aId, IModel<String> model)
    {

        super(aId);

        this.model = model;
        childPanel = new ChildPanel(MID, LoadableDetachableModel.of(this::getData));

        childPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(childPanel);

    }
LambdaAjaxButton button = new LambdaAjaxButton("button",
        (_target, _form) -> {

            //

        });
```

**ChildPanel**

```
 public ChildPanel(String aId, LoadableDetachableModel<String> loadableDetachableModel)

    {

        super(aId);

        childModel = loadableDetachableModel;

        component = new WebMarkupContainer(MID_COMPONENT_CONTAINER);
        component.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(component);

    }
```

I want to do such that the ChildPanel only renders when I click a button and never before. How do I define such thing in the onClick event? Also it must not render on initialization.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid component rendering you could try hiding your child panel and make it visible when you click on your AJAX button. You should also use LambdaModel instead of LoadableDetachableModel in order to call getData lazily. Something like this:

```
public Panel(String aId, IModel<String> model)
{

    super(aId);

    this.model = model;
    childPanel = new ChildPanel(MID, LambdaModel.of(this::getData));
    childPanel.setVisible(false);


    childPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag​(true);
    add(childPanel);

}
LambdaAjaxButton button = new LambdaAjaxButton("button",
    (_target, _form) -> {

        childPanel.setVisible(true);
        _target.add(childPanel);
    });
```

Comment: I am afraid that does not solve my problem. I want to only call the method `getData` once the button is clicked. Is it perhaps possible to add the child panel in the onClick event or better, give null as model to the child panel in the constructor and on click assign the model to it and re-render the child panel?

Comment: Then you should use LambdaModel instead of LoadableDetachableModel. I've updated my answer with LambdaModel.

Comment: BTW also LoadableDetachableModel.of should create a model that calls this::getData only when needed.